# Getting an cursor as result when using begin and end block

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

I'm trying to use the results of multiple slq statements for one result(cursor) in the firedac query editor:

Sql Command in editor

```
DECLARE
 MyVar1 varchar2(100);
 MyVar2 varchar2(100);

BEGIN
  SELECT USERINCDE INTO MyVar1 FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH1';
  SELECT USERINCDE INTO MyVar2 FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH2';
END;

SELECT MyVar1,MyVar2  AS TEST FROM DUAL
```

The above code wil not work as an select and begin and end block can not be combined.
Has Anyone sugestions for a working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it's a strange wish. If you wish to return some values from anonymous block, you should do something like this:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT USERINCDE INTO :MyVar1 FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH1';
  SELECT USERINCDE INTO :MyVar2 FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH2';
END;
```

But if you very-very need to use cursor, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE
 MyVar1 varchar2(100);
 MyVar2 varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT USERINCDE INTO MyVar1 FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH1';
  SELECT USERINCDE INTO MyVar2 FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH2';
  OPEN :result FOR SELECT MyVar1, MyVar2 AS TEST FROM DUAL;
END;
```

In last case result would be [ref cursor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Oracle_with_FireDAC#Working_with_Oracle_REF_CURSOR).

Answer (score 3):

Given your code, I assume each query returns *one and only one value*.

If this is correct, to achieve the desired result (1 row, 2 columns) you might use a `CROSS JOIN` :

```
  SELECT V1.USERINCDE MyVar1, V2.USERINCDE MyVar2 FROM
    (SELECT USERINCDE FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH1') V1
  CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT USERINCDE FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH2') V2;
```

Or simply two sub-queries:

```
  SELECT (SELECT USERINCDE FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH1') MyVar1,
         (SELECT USERINCDE FROM P_USR WHERE USEREXCDE='PH2') MyVar2 FROM DUAL
```